# Formula for Generalized Catalan Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

The Catalan numbers $C_n$ count the number of staircase walks from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ that lie below the diagonal $y=x$.  Let $C(n,k)$ denote the number of staircase walks from $(k,0)$ to $(n,n)$ that lie below the diagonal $y=x$.  E.g. $C(n,0)=C_n,\ C(n,n)=1,\ C(n,n-1)=n-1$.

I would like to know  if there is a nice formula, e.g. $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$ for the usual Catalan numbers, that applies to these generalized Catalan numbers.

Comment: Ballot Numbers ... see the second answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161243/ballot-numbers-sum-up-to-catalan-numbers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!